# install JAR package related to pyspark into foundry

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, conda, palantir-foundry

we would like to install [Spark-Alchemy](https://github.com/swoop-inc/spark-alchemy) to use it within Pyspark inside foundry (we would like to use their hyperloglog functions). While I know how to install a pip package, I am not sure what it is needed to install this kind of package.

Any help or alternative solutions related to the use of hyperloglog with pyspark will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

PySpark Transform repositories in Foundry are connected to conda. You can use the `coda_recipe/meta.yml` to pull packages into your transforms. If a package you want is not available in your channels, I would recommend you reach out to your administrators to ask if it's possible to add it. Adding a custom jar that extends spark is something that needs to be reviewed by your platform administrators since it can represent a security risk.

I did a `$ conda search spark-alchemy` and couldn't find anything related and reading through these instructions https://github.com/swoop-inc/spark-alchemy/wiki/Spark-HyperLogLog-Functions#python-interoperability it makes me guess that there isn't a conda package available.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment about the use of this specific library but in general, Foundry support Conda channels and if you have a Conda repo and configure foundry to connect to that channel you can add this library or others and reference them in your code.